# disable mouse hover when using frappe gantt

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart

I'm using this framework to show a simple grantt diagram in my application. I don't won't to modify the position or the dimension of a task, so I'm searching a way to prevent these changes, or, better to disable the mouse over. I prefer the second choice because when I move the mouse over a task, appear this "grey buttons" ( i don't know how can i call them) to modify the dimension or the progress of a task (like in the upper task).

I like to have a result like in the second task into the image

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "grey buttons" are called handles. You can simply hide them using CSS.

```css
.gantt .handle {
  display: none;
}
```

Now, they will be hidden and the mouse drag event will not work.

Comment: But whole task or event can still be moved

Answer (score 0):

For **all handles**:

```
.gantt .bar-wrapper:hover .handle {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

for the **progress** bar handle (triangle):

```
.gantt .bar-wrapper:hover .progress {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Just for the **right side** handle:

```
.gantt .bar-wrapper:hover .right {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Just for the **left side** handle:

```
.gantt .bar-wrapper:hover .right {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```